# Chrome extension that runs even if chrome closed

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that runs good when the chrome is opened. The problems is when the chrome application is closed.
I need to make the extension to run always - wheather the chrome browser is opened or closed.
Is there any way to make it happen that the extension will run even when chrome is closed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is exactly what the [`background` permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions#background) does:

> Makes Chrome start up early and and shut down late, so that apps and extensions can have a longer life.
>
> When any installed hosted app, packaged app, or extension has "background" permission, Chrome runs (invisibly) as soon as the user logs into their computer—before the user launches Chrome. The "background" permission also makes Chrome continue running (even after its last window is closed) until the user explicitly quits Chrome.

Simply add `"background"` to the permissions listed in your extension's `manifest.json`, and it will continue running before Chrome opens and after Chrome is closed.